# Once in a year or one in a year

Tags: usage

In the following sentence

> “I have other plans so have decided to move on. The CAC was anyway meeting once in a year or **one** in two years so I did not understand the conflict,” Ms. Rangaswamy told PTI.

[***Link***](https://www.thehindu.com/sport/cricket/rangaswamy-resigns-from-cac-and-ica-after-being-served-conflict-of-interest-notice/article29547625.ece?homepage=true)

I have never seen such usage **one in two years**. I think it should be **once**

Comment: The sentence posted might have a typo error: **one** in two years, or **once** in two years. I would have written "The CAC was anyway meeting once a year or every two years so I did not understand the conflict."

Comment: *once* would be better, but it can be understood as *one (time)*.

Answer (score 1):

This is awkward writing overall.

> The CAC was anyway meeting ....

is at best unusual, and arguably incorrect.

> meeting once in a year or one in two years

is at best inconsistent (if it is not a typo as a comment suggests) and might better be recast as:

> The CAC was only meeting once every year or two, so I did not understand the conflict.

But this seems to be reported speech, a spoken interview with a journalist, and may have been delivered off-the-cuff. In such a case a speaker often phrases things a bit awkwardly or loses track of exactly where a sentence was heading. The meanign is clear, which is all that can be hoped for in that situation.